# How do i log things in Cmd? (IP finder)

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, ip

This is my code. I am making an IP finder, for Fun and practice. I want to log all of the successful IPs on a separate line for each IP. As a note, successful meaning any IPs that I get a reply from.

```
:ModeB
CLS
Echo AutoMode On
ping %RANDOM:~-2%.%RANDOM:~-3%.%RANDOM:~-3%.%RANDOM:~-3%
goto ModeB
```

Basically, this will randomly generate numbers within dots and ping it. It does this repeatedly. Most of these IPs will not work, but it will get replies from some of them. I want to log the IPs I get at least one reply from, and then, and only then, will it truly be an IP finder. Any advice for this project will be appreciated.

Comment: Well I would start by understanding what a valid ip address is and what IP addresses are private ip address and which ones are route-able on the Internet.  Not to mention your code could have a leading zero in your numbers which will not be valid.  Also realize that some times firewalls do not respond to ping requests.

Answer (score 1):

- There is enough bad willed traffic in the internet, there is no need
  to be obtrusive.
- %Random% generates numbers between 0 .. 32768 [see here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html)
- an ip octet is 0 .. 255

your approach has the problem that while verifying the success of your ping you have to store the ipaddress, the next invocation of %random% has another random result.
You should read on redirection, for /f to parse the output of a command etc. ss64.com is a good starting point.

And please choose a different learning object-

Answer (score -1):

To start with, there are much more effective ways of scanning lots of ip's to see which are active, such as the free, open source tool [nmap](https://nmap.org/).

Using this method to find active hosts will most likely never find any considering the shear amount of possibilities an ip could be.

I'm not entirely sure batch actually has the capabilities to do what you are looking for, so I would recommend looking into other languages. As a recommendation, **VB.NET** and **Python** are good places to start.